# Can a Silverlight 3 out of browser application (OOB) host a html area?

Tags: html, silverlight, silverlight-3.0, out-of-browser

Is it possible to include a html area in a Silverlight 3 out of browser (OOB) application? Due to the fact that no html/dom bridge is accessible the DIV overlay does not work as far as I know.

Answer (score 1):

Its an old question but just to be complete the answer is: no it can't.

On the otherhand Silverlight 4 can in OOB mode.

Comment: If you can't wait, the major Silverlight control vendors make a control that allows you to embed HTML in an SL app.

Comment: @Dave: That's interesting, which vendors provide such a thing for out-of-browser environment?